Do you need a working VOR ground facility to fly a VOR approach if you have an FAA approved WAAS GPS? (e.g. G1000)
since TSO C145 and C146 are considered stand-alone units (you don't need an actual VOR receiver in a/c to fly the VOR approach or to fly on V airways), However, do the ground-based navaids (VOR) still have to be operational in order to fly these approaches, procedures and on these airways?

Yes.  The underlying NAVAID must be operational and used to fly a VOR approach.  Please reference AIM 1-2-3(c)(note #5).

C. Uses of Suitable RNAV Systems. Subject to the operating requirements, operators may use a suitable RNAV system in the following ways.




Determine aircraft position relative to, or distance from a VOR (see NOTE 6 below), TACAN, NDB, compass locator, DME fix; or a named fix defined by a VOR radial, TACAN course, NDB bearing, or compass locator bearing intersecting a VOR or localizer course.
Navigate to or from a VOR, TACAN, NDB, or compass locator.
Hold over a VOR, TACAN, NDB, compass locator, or DME fix.
Fly an arc based upon DME.

NOTE-


The allowances described in this section apply even when a facility is identified as required on a procedure (for example, “Note ADF required”).
These operations do not include lateral navigation on localizer-based courses (including localizer back-course guidance) without reference to raw localizer data.
Unless otherwise specified, a suitable RNAV system cannot be used for navigation on procedures that are identified as not authorized (“NA”) without exception by a NOTAM. For example, an operator may not use a RNAV system to navigate on a procedure affected by an expired or unsatisfactory flight inspection, or a procedure that is based upon a recently decommissioned NAVAID.
Pilots may not substitute for the NAVAID (for example, a VOR or NDB) providing lateral guidance for the final approach segment. This restriction does not refer to instrument approach procedures with “or GPS” in the title when using GPS or WAAS. These allowances do not apply to procedures that are identified as not authorized (NA) without exception by a NOTAM, as other conditions may still exist and result in a procedure not being available. For example, these allowances do not apply to a procedure associated with an expired or unsatisfactory flight inspection, or is based upon a recently decommissioned NAVAID.
Use of a suitable RNAV system as a means to navigate on the final approach segment of an instrument approach procedure based on a VOR, TACAN or NDB signal, is allowable. The underlying NAVAID must be operational and the NAVAID monitored for final segment course alignment.
For the purpose of paragraph c, “VOR” includes VOR, VOR/DME, and VORTAC facilities and “compass locator” includes locator outer marker and locator middle marker.




